# Return List using recursion with Racket

Tags: recursion, lisp, racket, binary-search-tree

I am trying to return a list (BST, a binary search tree) from a method that has double recursion. I am trying to implement it as follow:

```
(define (mapBST BST someFunct)
  (cond
    [(null? BST)
     '()]
       [else (cons (car BST) (someFunct (car (cdr BST)))) (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr BST))) someFunct) (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr (cdr BST)))) someFunct) ]

  )
)
```

This gets called with this little snippet of code

```
(define bst 
             '( 3 "3"
                  ( 1 "1"
                     ()
                     ( 2 "2" () ())
                  )
                  ( 5 "5" () () )
            )
) 
(mapBST bst string->number)
```

I also tried this snippet but it returned `((() ()) ())`:

```
[else (printf (car (cdr BST))) (cons (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr BST))) someFunct) (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr (cdr BST)))) someFunct)) ]
```

The result should return the same BST but with number instead of string as the value.

Comment: show the code you're calling, what it produces, and what you expected it to produce. indent your code properly, starting each sub-expression on new line. hint: in `[else A B C]`, `A` and `B` have no effect - their values are ignored, only the last value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Within your else-expression, you are not properly reconstructing the binary search tree, which is why you are getting an empty list. Changing your `else` case to

```
...
[else
 (cons (car BST)
       (cons (someFunct (car (cdr BST)))
             (cons (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr BST))) someFunct)
                   (cons (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr (cdr BST)))) someFunct) empty))))]
...
```

or

```
...
[else
 (list (car BST)
       (someFunct (car (cdr BST)))
       (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr BST))) someFunct)
       (mapBST (car (cdr (cdr (cdr BST)))) someFunct))]
...
```

will fix your problem (both options produce the same list, since `(cons 1 (cons 2 empty))` is equivalent to `(list 1 2)`).

Here is a full update of `mapBST`:

```
(define (mapBST proc BST)
  (cond
    [(null? BST) empty]
    [else
     (list (car BST)
           (proc (cadr BST))
           (mapBST proc (caddr BST))
           (mapBST proc (cadddr BST)))]))
```

For example,

```
(define BST '(3 "3" (1 "1" () (2 "2" () ())) (5 "5" () ())))
(mapBST string->number BST)
=> '(3 3 (1 1 () (2 2 () ())) (5 5 () ()))
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in another answer, you are not actually returning what you think you are in the `else` clause.  Fixing that will make your program work.  However this kind of `(car (cdr (cdr ...)))` thing is how people used to write Lisp in the 1960s, and it rightly got Lisp a bad name because it is utterly opaque.  Using things like `caddr` is better, but only slightly (and how many of them does the language provide?  I can never remember).  Still better, if your data is conceptually a list, is to use functions with names like `first` & `second` because they say what you actually *mean* (if your data is conceptually a tree of conses, then `car` &c are better probably).  But they still have the 'how many of them are there this week' problem.

The right solution is to use destructuring &/or pattern matching to bind variables according to the shape of your data.  This makes your code actually clear.  Racket has a comprehensive mechanism for this, which I don't really understand in detail, but I know enough to get me through.  Here is (a fixed) version of your function which uses `match` to do the work:

```
(define (map-bst bst fn)
  (match bst
    ['() '()]
    [(list 1st 2nd 3rd 4th)
     (list 1st
           (fn 2nd)
           (map-bst 3rd fn)
           (map-bst 4th fn))]
    [_ (error "botch")]))
```

(note this could do with better variable names: I don't know what the various bits of the structure mean).